# How to add memory to the heap at runtime?

Tags: embedded, heap-memory, keil

I am using Keil's ARM-MDK 4.11.  I have a statically allocated block of memory that is used only at startup.  It is used before the scheduler is initialised and due to the way RL-RTX takes control of the heap-management, cannot be dynamically allocated (else subsequent allocations after the scheduler starts cause a hard-fault).

I would like to add this static block as a free-block to the system heap after the scheduler is initialised.  It would seem that [__Heap_ProvideMemory()](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0205g/Cihfjiea.html) might provide the answer, this is called during initialisation to create the initial heap.  However that would require knowledge of the heap descriptor address, and I can find no documented method of obtaining that.

Any ideas?

I have raised a support request with ARM/Keil for this, but they are more interested in questioning why I would want to do this, and offering alternative solutions.  I am well aware of the alternatives, but in this case if this could be done it would be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

We use the Rowley Crossworks compiler but had a similar issue - the heap was being set up in the compiler CRT startup code. Unfortunately the SDRAM wasn't initialised till the start of main() and so the heap wasn't set up properly. I worked around it by reinitialising the heap at the start of main(), after the SDRAM was initialised.

I looked at the assembler code that the compiler uses at startup to work out the structure - it wasn't hard. Subsequently I have also obtained the malloc/free source code from Rowley - perhaps you could ask Keil for their version?

Comment: Reverse engineering may be the solution, but it makes the code susceptible to being broken when the tool-chain is upgraded.  An alternative I am considering is making the root task far simpler (thus requiring minimal stack allocation), and spawning from it a normal task to do initialisation, so that its stack can be dynamically allocated and thus reusable.  As they say there is no problem that cannot be solved without yet another level of indirection (except the problem of too many levels of indirection)!  Keil's source license for the RL-ARM library is available for a fee.

Answer (score 1):

One method I've used is to incorporate my own simple heap routines and take over the `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`free()` functions from the library.

The simple, custom heap routines had an interface that allowed adding blocks of memory to the heap.

The drawback to this (at least in my case) was that the custom heap routines were far less sophisticated than the built-in library routines and were probably more prone to fragmentation than the built-in routines. That wasn't a serious issue in that particular application. If you want the capabilities of the built-in library routines, you could probably have your `malloc()` defer to the built-in heap routines until it returns a failure, then try to allocate from your custom heap.

Another drawback is that I found it much more painful to make sure the custom routines were bug-free than I thought it would be at first glance, even though I wasn't trying to do anything too fancy (just a simple list of free blocks that could be split on allocation and coalesced when freed).

The one benefit to this technique is that it's pretty portable (as long as your custom routines are portable) and doesn't break if the toolchain changes it's internals.  The only part that requires porting is taking over the `malloc()`/`free()` interface and making sure you get initialized early enough.

Comment: Some good ideas, complicated somewhat by the fact that I am using C++ new/delete perhaps, and I'd have ot handle thread safety which the RTX provided versiuons do.  I am thinking now that I could reverse-engineer the block management structure that preceeds an allocation, replicate it the the start of the static block, then free() it to get it added to the free list.

Comment: C++ `new`/`delete` might make things easier (at least some things).  C++ directly supports end-user overriding of global `new`/`delete` - you can do that 100% portably. If you don't care that some heap allocations might bypass the custom heap you can forget about hijacking `malloc`/`free` and just override `new`/`delete`.